# Can someone please explain what is meant by "5 level lower" with Kineticist Archetype Elemental Purist's Limited Buffer feature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype, kineticist

Can some one please explain what is meant by "5 levels lower" with Kineticist Archetype Elemental Purist's [Limited Buffer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/archetypes/paizo-llc-kineticist-archetypes/elemental-purist-kineticist-archetype/#Limited_Buffer_Su) feature?

So far I get that you just get it and it benefits later at level 11. Isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Internal Buffer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/#TOC-Internal-Buffer-Su-)'s benefits scale with your Kineticist level.  It starts at 1 point maximum and goes to 2 at level 11, and 3 at level 16.

Limited Buffer's

> treats her kineticist level as 5 lower for the purpose of the
>   ability.

line means you subtract 5 from your kineticist level to determine what benefits you get from the Internal Buffer ability.  In particular when you get it at level 11 your limit is still 1 point since your level is 11-5=6.  You'll get a second point at level 16, and the third point at level 21 [(If your game allows for advancement beyond 20th)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Classes/character-advancement/#Advancing_Beyond_20th_Level)

Comment: This is correct—+1—but Pathfinder does not support any 21st level, so it might be worth putting an asterisk on that.